# Wrong dimensions doing simple 'merge' in R

Tags: r, merge, left-join, dplyr

I've been an R user for too long for this problem to arise, and I need your help (embarrassingly).

I've got two data sets:

```
> dim(markus301_rms.df)
[1] 743  15
> dim(markus301_envel.df)
[1] 743  15
```

that share a common column, which is filled with the exactly the same strings:

```
> class(markus301_envel.df$soundname)
[1] "character"
> class(markus301_rms.df$soundname)
[1] "character"
> setdiff(markus301_rms.df$soundname,markus301_envel.df$soundname)
character(0)
```

and therefore would be suitable for merging the two sets into a 743x29 data frame.

Now, this is what happens:

```
dim(merge(markus301_rms.df,markus301_envel.df,by="soundname"))
[1] 1485   29
```

The number of columns is as expected, but the number of rows is almost the double. `merge`has been able to identify only a singe duplicate entry in the two sets, while `setdiff` identified all of them as duplicates.

Oddly enough, `dplyr` behaves the same:

```
> require(dplyr)
> markus301_rms.df %>% full_join(markus301_envel.df,by="soundname") %>% dim()
[1] 1485   29
> markus301_rms.df %>% left_join(markus301_envel.df,by="soundname") %>% dim()
[1] 1485   29
> markus301_rms.df %>% right_join(markus301_envel.df,by="soundname") %>% dim()
[1] 1485   29
```

I have not been in this situation before.

What may be wrong with my indexing column???

EDIT: Information on my machine:

```
> Sys.info()
                                                                                           sysname 
                                                                                          "Darwin" 
                                                                                           release 
                                                                                          "15.5.0" 
                                                                                           version 
"Darwin Kernel Version 15.5.0: Tue Apr 19 18:36:36 PDT 2016; root:xnu-3248.50.21~8/RELEASE_X86_64" 
                                                                                          nodename 
                                                             "Fredrik-Karlssons-Macbook-Air.local" 
                                                                                           machine 
                                                                                          "x86_64"
```

Comment: Can you simulate a small dataset that demonstrates this behavior? Note that while classes may be the same, string representations may not be (this is not clear from your example).

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any duplicate values in both of your index columns? I.e. is `sum(duplicated(markus301_envel.df$soundname))` equal to 0?

Comment: What do `table(duplicated(markus301_envel.df$soundname))` and `table(duplicated(markus301_rms.df$soundname))` say?

Comment: Yes! That's it! I do have duplicated values (although I shouldn't, but that's a different issue) in both sets, so with all combinations of matches, then I am likely to get the results I am getting. Excellent! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Are you sure that you don't have any duplicate values in both of your
> index columns? I.e. is sum(duplicated(markus301_envel.df$soundname))
> equal to 0? – jkt 11 mins ago
>
> What do table(duplicated(markus301_envel.df$soundname)) and
> table(duplicated(markus301_rms.df$soundname)) say? – Jan van der Laan
> 7 mins ago

Sorry for not being able to promote your comments to answers, but Thanks!